# CSS button background dissapears when hovering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap in combination with my own CSS abilities to make somehow nice websites. And I have this strange problem today and can't figure it out why is this happening.

```css
.container-fluid {
  text-align: center;
}
#toplane {
  color: white;
  /*background-image:  url(citybackground.jpg);
    using a background color due to image not uploaded
  into the net yet*/
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-height: 370px;
}
#botlane {} #headone {
  margin-top: 130px;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 12px white, 0px 0px 8px white, 0px 0px 3px white, 0px 0px 5px white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, monospace;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.buscado {
  color: #595959;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wean1.css">
<div class="container-fluid" id="toplane">
  <h1 id="headone">PRICE SURFER FAQ</h1>
  <button class="buscado"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="botlane">

</div>
```

In the snippet linked above, you can see that the search button has a hover effect even when not intended. I have tried creating a `.buscador:hover` to solve it but the thing I cannot change doesn't matter what I write it's the button becoming transparent when hovering the mouse over it.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:** here's an image with what's happening to me *(Ubuntu doesn't like me taking screenshots today i guess, sorry for pic)*: [image: Don't ask why had to take a picture]

Comment: I can't see anythign happening like you describe... Besides, there's no bootstrap classes on this button, so this question isn't related to Bootstrap at all

Comment: @Lee the round button under the H1 dissapears when you hover the mouse over it.

Comment: @Lee it does it on Firefox at least, haven't tried with other explorers.

Comment: It's not disappearing for me, I'm using FireFox right now. Like I said earlier, I don't think there's an issue here, as we can't replicate it. But it's certainly nothing to do with Bootstrap, as you're not using any bootstrap classes for the button.

Comment: Doesn’t disappear on a current Firefox either for me. (Win 7, FF 48.0)

Comment: Doesn't disappear for me too (win7, Chrome)

Comment: Doesn't disappear on Chrome either (Ubuntu here). Interestingly, nothing happens on chrome but in Firefox the background goes from silverish to black. Maybe is that what op means?...

Comment: If a bootstrap class was being used on the button at least, it wouldn't be doing anything strange like this. @Yacomini, you should apply one of the Bootstrap classes to the button, an then create overrides in your stylesheet to adapt it to how you want.

Comment: @Lee check new edit. That's happening

Comment: Have you tried adding standard Bootstrap classes (for the fourth time) ie. `btn btn-primary` to see if it still does it when hovering?

Comment: @Lee adding the class changes the button enterily and if I add the modifications to it, it still dissapears for me. But apparently I'm the only one who cannot see it, so I guess it may be an internal issue. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: So if you just use Bootstrap classes, the problem isn't there? In which case it's not your browser or anything, it will be your custom CSS. You can inspect, set it to Hover state, and see exactly what your CSS is doing in the inspector panel.

Comment: @Lee I can't see nothing weird happening, maybe I'm dumb but it looks completely normal to me. Also, tested it on chrome and work correctly. So i guess is a firefox problem.

Comment: It's a CSS problem, you're probably not providing a suitable FF compatible style.

Comment: @Lee problem persists without boostrap, editing post. Where can i find specific FF compatible styles?